# ASP.NET Identity DbContext Issue with EF Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

EDIT2:
I used this "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" for the connection string, and everything worked as expected. I guess i'm doing something stupid with sqlexpress.

---

I'm trying to create a simple database for users, using ASP.NET(4.5) Identity(2.2) and EF(6) Code First migrations, based on [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/)

The problem  only happens when ApplicationDbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext.

So,first, i create an empty asp.net project. 
Then the Entity class for the users:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AspNetIdentity.Infrastructure
{
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Level { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Then i create the DbContext class:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

So far so good. Now here is the issue:
I add the connection string in the web.config as shown below

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data      
  Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AspNetIdentity;Integrated    
  Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and when i run

```
enable-migrations
```

i get the following error:

**An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the      connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.**

If i try the exact same things, but with normal DbContext everything goes as expected. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? This thing is bugging me for days now.

---

EDIT1:
Below is the full output in the console, which is huge so im attaching them as images, i hope thats ok.

[image: output_first_part]
[image: output_second_part]

If the error is too obvious in there, i'm sorry, but im a newbie :)

Comment: Aren't you by chance defining the connection string in a config file of a different assembly than the one that contains the context?

Comment: If you have your EF code in a separate assembly, you will need one connection string for running things from the PM console that lives in the same assembly (app.config), and then one for the web config for when it's deployed.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Everything is in the same project. I actually just followed the tutorial I posted step by step.

Comment: @Nikki9696  Everything is in the same project. I actually just followed the tutorial I posted step by step.

Comment: Do you have any inner exception? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Ok, a naive question but still. Are you sure you have the sql express at '.\sqlexpress' and the database is there?

Comment: @MihailStancescu I added the output in the answer :)

Comment: The exception message says there is no sql server available at `.\sqlexpress`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Indeed it does. I do have installed SQLExpress though. Should i specify the path to the folder, or something else? I thought Im suppose to leave it as is, at least there was nothing mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: You need another tutorial, about installing and managing sqlexpress. There are few things to pay attention to but too many to put them all here in a comment.

Comment: So your connection string is no longer for SQL Server Express, but LocalDB, which is installed with Visual Studio (and is very similar to SQL Server Express). It looks like you don't _actually_ have A SQL Server Express instance installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two things not to forget about SQL Express: enable TCP/IP protocol + enable and start SQL Browser windows service. Also firewall may be the reason. Please see if the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2005/05/05/how-to-configure-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

in Visual studio press control+alt+s and check do You see Your Db in Data Connections ,
also in Solution explorer click "show all files" and check App_Data folder.
 If You don't see your db or You see different db name ,the problem is in Your connection string.
 If You're just testing db connections and there's no important data try to delete migrations folder and rename your base and default connection in connection string .
After this enable migrations ,add migration and then update your DB.
 hope it helps Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am new in ASP.NET, but I have modified the connectionStrings to use localdb:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
      connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```